# finding difficulty mocking request.referrer from feature specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, referrer

From my rspec FEATURE test I want to set request.referrer to '/pagea'.

Following is my test:

```
controller.request.should_receive(:referrer).and_return('/pagea')
visit '/pageb'

expect(page).to have_content 'xyz'
```

This is the error I face:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups
```

Then when I change the line to

```
AbcController.request.should_receive(:referrer).and_return('/pagea')
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `request' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups
```

The source code is as follows:

```
class AbcController < ApplicationController
  def index
     set_defaults
  end

  def set_defaults
   if request.referrer.present?
     check_user
   end
  end

  def check_user
    if request.referrer.include? "/pagea"
      @field = true
    end
  end

end
```

Could you help me figure out how to mock the request.referrer.

Comment: i think it's `@controller` instead of `controller`

Comment: Have you tried `AbcController.new.request.should_receive(:refereer).....`?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the controller directly from feature specs (which is where capybara is used), feature tests are to test your application like a user.  You should be writing a request or controller spec.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this

```rb
allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:referrer).and_return('/pagea')
```